# Objective c, Chat messaging app and identifying time zones

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a chat app that allows users world wide to send messages and each message will have a time for when the message has been sent. For example if I sent a message at 12 and that is my uk local time how would I display the time I sent the message to the correct time zone when received in USA or another country

### UPDATE

The time still reflects the server time which is 1 hour forward, i created the timestamp at 12:05 but when i receive the timestamp from the database and display the time i get 13:05 which is incorrect as the time should be 12:05.

The data type used to store the timestamp in the table is int(11).

This is where i create the client side timestamp:

```
                CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
            UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
            activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
            activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, screenRect.size.width, screenRect.size.height);
            activityIndicator.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f/255 green:0.0f/255 blue:0.0f/255 alpha:0.9f];
            activityIndicator.center = self.view.center;
            [self.view addSubview: activityIndicator];

            [activityIndicator startAnimating];

            dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

            // 3) Load picker in background
            dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, ^{

                NSTimeInterval timeStamp = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];

                NSString *myRequestString = [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"ThreadName=%@&ThreadDesc=%@&CatId=%d&UID=%d&TimeStamp=%f", textFieldThreadName.text, textFieldThreadDesc.text, rowCategory, self.userID, timeStamp];
                NSString *response = [self setupPhpCall:myRequestString :@"insertThread.php"];

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self insertedThread:response];
                [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
                });

            });
```

This is how i retrieve the timestamp and display it:

```
    if((NSNull *)[dict objectForKey:@"T_Created"] != [NSNull null]){
        NSString *timestampString = [dict objectForKey:@"T_Created"];
        double timestampDate = [timestampString doubleValue];
        t_Created = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timestampDate];
    }
```

### UPDATE

Where i retrieve the data from database:

```
-(void)renderThreadInfo:(NSDictionary*)dic{

        NSDictionary *thread = [dic objectForKey:@"thread"];

        if((NSNull*)thread != [NSNull null]){

        int t_ID;
        int t_U_ID;
        int t_C_ID;
        NSString *t_Name;
        NSString *t_Description;
        NSDate *t_Created;
        int t_Flagged;
        int t_Rated;
        NSString *firstName;
        NSString *lastName;
        NSString *categoryName;

        for(NSDictionary *dict in thread)
        {
        if((NSNull *)[dict objectForKey:@"T_ID"] != [NSNull null]){
            t_ID = [[dict objectForKey:@"T_ID"] intValue];
        }
        if((NSNull *)[dict objectForKey:@"T_U_ID"] != [NSNull null]){
            t_U_ID = [[dict objectForKey:@"T_U_ID"] intValue];
        }
        if((NSNull *)[dict objectForKey:@"T_C_ID"] != [NSNull null]){
            t_C_ID = [[dict objectForKey:@"T_C_ID"] intValue];
        }
        if((NSNull *)[dict objectForKey:@"T_Name"] != [NSNull null]){
            t_Name = [dict objectForKey:@"T_Name"];
        }
        if((NSNull *)[dict objectForKey:@"T_Description"] != [NSNull null]){
            t_Description = [dict objectForKey:@"T_Description"];
        }
        if((NSNull *)[dict objectForKey:@"T_Created"] != [NSNull null]){
            NSString *timestampString = [dict objectForKey:@"T_Created"];
            double timestampDate = [timestampString doubleValue];
            t_Created = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timestampDate];
        }
        if((NSNull *)[dict objectForKey:@"T_Flagged"] != [NSNull null]){
            t_Flagged = [[dict objectForKey:@"T_Flagged"] intValue];
        }
        if((NSNull *)[dict objectForKey:@"T_Rated"] != [NSNull null]){
            t_Rated = [[dict objectForKey:@"T_Rated"] intValue];
        }
        if((NSNull *)[dict objectForKey:@"U_FirstName"] != [NSNull null]){
            firstName = [dict objectForKey:@"U_FirstName"];
        }
        if((NSNull *)[dict objectForKey:@"U_LastName"] != [NSNull null]){
            lastName = [dict objectForKey:@"U_LastName"];
        }
        if((NSNull *)[dict objectForKey:@"C_Name"] != [NSNull null]){
            categoryName = [dict objectForKey:@"C_Name"];
        }

        ThreadInfo *threadObj = [ThreadInfo new];
        threadObj.iD = t_ID;
        threadObj.userId  = t_U_ID;
        threadObj.catId = t_C_ID;
        threadObj.name = t_Name;
        threadObj.description = t_Description;
        threadObj.timeStampCreated = t_Created;
        threadObj.flagged = t_Flagged;
        threadObj.rated = t_Rated;
        threadObj.firstName = firstName;
        threadObj.lastName = lastName;
        threadObj.category = categoryName;

        [threadsArray addObject:threadObj];

        [tableViewThreads reloadData];

        }

        }

    }
```

And where the UI displays the date:

```
    -(UIView*)setupThreadItem:(ThreadInfo*)threadInfo{

        CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
        UIView *threadInfoView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, screenRect.size.width - 10, 112)];
        threadInfoView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:188.0f/255 green:188.0f/255 blue:188.0f/255 alpha:1.0f];
        threadInfoView.tag  = threadInfo.iD;

        UILabel *labelFirstName = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 16)];
        labelFirstName.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:136.0f/255 green:135.0f/255 blue:135.0f/255 alpha:1.0f];
        labelFirstName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", threadInfo.firstName,threadInfo.lastName];
        //labelFirstName.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        labelFirstName.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:13];
        labelFirstName.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [threadInfoView addSubview:labelFirstName];

        UILabel *labelTimestamp = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140, 10, 220, 16)];
        labelTimestamp.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        labelTimestamp.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", threadInfo.timeStampCreated];
        //labelFirstName.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        labelTimestamp.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:13];
        //labelFirstName.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [threadInfoView addSubview:labelTimestamp];

        return threadInfoView;

    }
```

Comment: 1) Determine the timezone at the other end.  2) Set the timezone of the DateFormatter accordingly.

Comment: I would store them on the server as absolute timestamps, then convert client side to the appropriate time for their location.

Comment: So I would get the time from example USA time and store this in the database then use the dateformatter but how would the data in the database for that time know that the time is based in USA

Comment: (It goes without saying that any stored date values should be UTC.)

Comment: What you're using to store the data is irrelevant to this discussion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When sending a message, record this time stamp and save it to your server.

```
// This is an absolute time based on GMT
NSTimeInterval timeStamp = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
```

On client side:

```
NSDate *sentAt = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeStamp];
// Format sentAt appropriately for current user.
```

Comment: That's weird, timeIntervalSince1970 is an absolute time based on Jan 1, 1970 GMT.  The value shouldn't be possible to change.  Have you logged the actual timestamp number to make sure it's the same and something else isn't getting changed?

Comment: well the timestamp was something like 1422454524545.544545 but when i store it in the database as int(11) the timestamp gets stored as 1422454524545 without the decimal and following numbers after the decimal

Comment: Yeah, those are milliseconds so wouldn't account for the whole hour.  How are you displaying the date?  Have you set the timezone to the client's current timezone before formatting/displaying?  Just using something like `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", date];` will display in GMT timeZone.  Can you show how you're showing the user?

Comment: its weird when i hover over the variable that stores the timestamp its correct but when i look into the information it shows an hour in front. so why is the variable being set from the information when i debug

Comment: this is how i display the date: NSString *timestampString = [dict objectForKey:@"T_Created"];
            double timestampDate = [timestampString doubleValue];
            t_Created = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timestampDate];

Comment: Ok, so you have `t_created`, but how do you display that in UI?  Where is it showing that it's an hour ahead?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60909/discussion-between-redoc01-and-logan).